# NSMutableAttributedString conversion to string while keeping the formatting

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I want to assign a header title for my table view, but I want the title to be in two lines. The second line should have a smaller font than the top line.

I am trying to use `NSMutableAttributedString`, but in the method:

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

But it returns a `NSString` instead of `NSMutableAttributedString`.

Is there any way that I can convert the `NSMutableAttributedString` to `NSString` while keeping the formatting of the string?

Here is my code:

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSString *title = @"";
    title = @"Top Line \n";
    if(_favouriteLocations.count == 0){
        title = [title stringByAppendingString:@"Smaller font Bottom Line"];
    }
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title];
    NSRange range = [title rangeOfString:@"Smaller"];

    [attString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:@"8"} range:NSMakeRange(range.location, title.length - range.location)];

     NSLog(@"%@", attString);
     title = [attString string];

     return title;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way of doing this using the [`tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:) method.
You need to use [`tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:) which is a [`UITableViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate) method and return a [`UILabel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILabel) with the [`attributedText`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/attributedText) set

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *title = @"";
    title = @"Top Line \n";
    if(_favouriteLocations.count == 0){
        title = [title stringByAppendingString:@"Smaller font Bottom Line"];
    }
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title];
    NSRange range = [title rangeOfString:@"Smaller"];

    [attString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:@"8"} range:NSMakeRange(range.location, title.length - range.location)];

     UILabel *titleLabel = [UILabel new];
     titleLabel.attributedText = attString;

     return titleLabel;
}
```

If you've got a lot of sections you could also use the newer [`UITableViewHeaderFooterView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewHeaderFooterView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewHeaderFooterView/textLabel) class and [dequeue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:) that. That view has a [`textLabel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewHeaderFooterView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewHeaderFooterView/textLabel) property and just like above you could set the `attributedText` on that. Its a bit more code but more efficient as you then don't return a newly created view each time.

```
static NSString *const HeaderCellId = @"header_id";

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Setup table view
    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:HeaderCellId];
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *title = @"";
    title = @"Top Line \n";
    if(_favouriteLocations.count == 0){
        title = [title stringByAppendingString:@"Smaller font Bottom Line"];
    }
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title];
    NSRange range = [title rangeOfString:@"Smaller"];

    [attString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:@"8"} range:NSMakeRange(range.location, title.length - range.location)];

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *view = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:HeaderCellId];

    view.textLabel.attributedText = attString;

    return view;
}
```

*EDIT*:

As noted by @PabloRomeu in the comments `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` only works if [`tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:) is implemented returning a non-zero value.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 80;
}
```

Comment: A little comment on this. Apple says: "This method only works correctly when tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: is also implemented."

Comment: actually, tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: is a method of UITableViewDelegate, not of UITableViewDataSource

Comment: @marcelnijman - thanks, looks like link to method was right anyway

Answer (score 0):

Implement this tableview delegate method,

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

And return a UILabel with a `AttributedString` set to it's `text` value